# ASP.NET MVC Redirect to target page or redirect to previous page after login

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following issue using asp.net MVC: When the admin updates the user request, he will receive an e-mail telling that the request had been update and in this email there will be the link to the page `http://www.domain.com/request`.

To access that page the user must be logged in so the link will redirect to the login page. After the login the user is redirected to `http://www.domain.com/welcome`, 
how can I do to redirect to the address sent on the email after logging in?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl, bool createPersistentCookie)
{
    // Check if the Model is valid or not
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (GNEntities entities = new GNEntities())
        {
            string username = model.Email;
            string password = model.Password;

            // Now if our password was enctypted or hashed we would have done the
            // same operation on the user entered password here, But for now
            // since the password is in plain text lets just authenticate directly


            bool userValid = entities.Employee.Any(user => user.Email == username && user.Password == password && user.IsActive ==true);

            // User found in the database
            if (userValid)
            {

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, createPersistentCookie); //false:not persistent cookie

                Employee e = (Employee)entities.Employee.FirstOrDefault(user => user.Email == username);


                if (e.Roles.Id==1 || e.RoleId == 3) // 3 = commercial
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminIndex", new { Area = "AdminArea" });
                }
                else if (e.Roles.Id == 2 || e.Roles.Id ==4)
                {
                    int countryId = e.CountryId;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Calendar", new { year = DateTime.Now.Year, countryId, Area = "EmpArea" });//with paramenters RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = currentcoupon.Companyid.id, Area="Admin" });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The email or password provided is incorrect or your account has been disabled.");
            }
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
```

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
if (returnUrl == null)
{
    int countryId = e.CountryId;
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Calendar", new { year = DateTime.Now.Year, countryId, Area = "EmpArea" });
}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction(returnUrl, new {Area = "EmpArea"});
}
```

The result still not good:
This is the url before login `domain.net/Login/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fEmpArea%2fTimesheet`

and after login it generates this url `domain.net/EmpArea/Login/EmpArea/Timesheet`

It keeps the login Area I don't know why.

Comment: Perhaps show us your login code?

Comment: In your login code, after login you then redirect the user to the AdminIndex or Calendar. Try using the returnUrl parameter instead.

Comment: Hi David, I added the RedirectToAction(returnURL, new = {Area = "EmpArea"}) but I am still having and error. This is the url before login domain.net/Login/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fEmpArea%2fTimesheet and after login it generates this url domain.net/EmpArea/Login/EmpArea/Timesheet

Comment: returnUrl isn't an action name, it's a full URL, use `Redirect(returnUrl)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your login code, after the credentials have been successfully validated you are redirecting the user to either `AdminIndex` or `Calendar`. Note that the `Login` action has a `returnUrl` parameter that you can use.

So after you successfully login, check the parameter isn't empty and [redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) the user to that URL:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
```